# Como fazer um if/else dentro de uma rota?

Tags: laravel, if, else, rotas

Eu tenho um formulário que possui dois tipos de usuários: administradores e desenvolvedores e cada um tem sua página pós login, porém, mesmo logada como administradora, eu consigo ir para as páginas dos desenvolvedores. Preciso arrumar isso!

Comment: É só fazer uma Middleware nas rota. Na middleware você faz o `if` perguntando se o usuário logado é um Admin ou User.

Comment: Mas como? Sou nova no Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual versão do Laravel você está utilizando mas se for 5.2 ou superior, o mesmo já possui nativamente controle para diferentes tipos de autenticação, chamado de "guard", na pasta do seu projeto vá em config/auth.php, lá tem um array com os "guards", vc pode fazer assim por exemplo:

```
   'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'desenvolvedor' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'desenvolvedores',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
]
```

será necessário alterar o array de providers também neste mesmo arquivo "auth.php", coloque o provider assim:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'desenvolvedores' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Desenvolvedor::class,
    ]       
]
```

note que no provider você especifica o model que será utilizado para realizar a autenticação, você pode duplicar o model User e alterar ele para Desenvolvedor, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Desenvolvedor extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'desenvolvedores'; //coloque aqui o nome da tabela dos desenvolvedores
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

você também irá precisar ter os campos 'name', 'email' e 'password' na sua tabela de desenvolvedores, sugiro que siga o padrão da tabela "users".

dessa forma você poderá criar rotas protegidas para cada "guard", por exemplo:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/desenvolvedor', 'middleware' => 'auth:desenvolvedor'], function ()...
```

para maiores detalhes sugiro que leia a documentação em: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: Não funcionou... D:

Comment: Editei minha resposta detalhando as outras alterações que vc deve fazer, se não funcionar, diga o que não funcionou, que retorno você teve.

Comment: Por que eu faço isso só com os desenvolvedores, e os administradores não?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso para os administradores também, estou pressupondo que vc está utilizando a tabela users para administradores, se não estiver pode fazer a mesma coisa para os administradores, e nas rotas de administradores você coloca 'auth:administradores' por exemplo.

Comment: Eu fiz tudo e o Adm continua podendo ver a página do Desenvolvedor e vice versa... Não dá erro algum, mas tbm n funciona!

Comment: coloque aqui como vc colocou suas rotas para o adm e para o desenvolvedor que vou tentar identificar onde está o problema.

Answer (score 0):

1. Criar uma Middleware. Abra o **Prompt de Comando**, vá até a pasta do seu projeto e digite:

   ```
   php artisan make:middleware CheckRoleUser
   ```
2. Registre essa Middleware no `App/Http/Kernel.php` em `$routeMiddleware`

   ```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'check_role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoleUser::class,
       .
       .
       .
   ];
   ```
3. Abra o arquivo `App/Http/Middleware/CheckRoleUser.php` e escreva a rotina de códigos que verifica se o usuário é um Admin ou Desenvolvedor. Não sei como é sua base de dados. Mas a tabela `users` deve ter um campo `role` ou `role_id` que define o tipo do usuário.

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){

       # Se for diferente de 1 = Admin volta para página de login.
       if (!Auth::user()->role == 1) {
           return redirect()->to('/login');
       }

       return $next($request);

   }
   ```
4. No arquivo `App/Http/routes.php` você chama a Middleware criada com o nome que definiu no `Kernel.php`.

   ```
   # Admin
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'check_role'], function(){
       Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
   });
   ```

Comment: Essa última parte da rota eu não entendi bem. Que view eu coloco?

Comment: Você não fará nada na View...

Comment: Route::get('/', 'RegisterController@index');... Qual view eu mando retornar?

Comment: A qual você quiser. Daí é com você... A parte da permissão está feita, caso tenha seguido esses passos.

Comment: Está dando erro na rota...